# Seeing the actual content of a list in the "Run and Debug" window in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently started learning Java using VS Code and I am trying to configure it to meet my needs. Right now I'm debugging a test program I'm writing where I have an `ArrayList` of `Integers`, but the issue I'm facing is that the debugger doesn't show the values of the list directly and it shows instead "Integer@52".

[image: see screenshot]

Is there any way to configure VS Code to show the integer value directly without needing to click on each item?

- I tried searching in Google:

> java vscode list show values

and

> java vscode show list values automatically

- Asked this to ChatGPT:

> "I open the list contents in the "Run and Debug" window but the contents are hidden and I need to
> click on each individual item to see what value it holds. Instead of showing me the value it shows "Integer@52"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click and select `Enable 'toString()' Object View`

[image]

Then you can see the value directly

[image]

Meanwhile, if you want the debugger to automatically expand the value for you instead of manually click the 'eye' icon to expand the variable. You can turn on the setting `debug.autoExpandLazyVariables`

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I had the 'toString()' option on, but I still couldn't see the values of each element. Turning on the `debug.autoExpandLazyVariables` fixed my issue directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an box object (`Integer` and not `int`). It's not unreasonable for it to be displayed in the debugger accordingly. There are real differences, such as the result of the `==` (identity/address comparison) operator.

At the time of this writing, I don't see a setting that sounds related to showing unboxed values of box types in [the package.json of the Java debugger extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/package.json). Either I'm missing something, or no such feature exists right now.

I tried looking for existing feature-request issue tickets by googling "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug box OR unbox "type"`", but didn't find anything that looked relevant. You could [write a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/new) requesting for such a feature.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.